How to initialize data at startup and get it in handler? [aiogram 3]
I am using an ML model. I need to initialize the model at start and pass (or receive) model and tokenizer to the handler to make it run the model. How to do this?
Right now I am using FSMContext and the model is loaded and saved on /start command for each user separately.
Structure:
model.py
def load_model():
    return model
def load_tokenizer():
    return tokenizer
def run_model(model, tokenizer):
    <...>
    return output

bot.py
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.TOKEN = "TOKEN"

        self.storage = MemoryStorage()
        self.dp = Dispatcher(storage=self.storage)

    async def main(self):
        self.bot = Bot(token=self.TOKEN)
        self.dp.include_routers(
            start_handler.router,
            main_handler.router,
        )
        await self.dp.start_polling(self.bot)
asyncio.run(TelegramBot().main())

main_handler.py
async def main_handler(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    model = data["model"]
    tokenizer = data["tokenizer"]
    result = run_model(model, tokenizer)
    await message.answer(result)

start_handler.py
from model import load_model, load_tokenizer

async def start_handler(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_data(
        {
            "model": load_model(),
            "tokenizer": load_tokenizer()
        }
    )


Create a middleware that will load the model and tokenizer once and make them available to handlers.
middleware.py
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware

class ModelMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, model, tokenizer):
        self.model = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    async def __call__(self, handler, event, data: dict):
        data['model'] = self.model
        data['tokenizer'] = self.tokenizer
        return await handler(event, data)

Initialize the model and tokenizer in bot.py and add the middleware to the dispatcher.
bot.py
from middleware import ModelMiddleware

class TelegramBot: 
    async def main(self):
        self.dp = Dispatcher()
        self.bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
        
        model = load_model()
        tokenizer = load_tokenizer()
        
        self.dp.message.middleware(ModelMiddleware(model, tokenizer))

        await self.dp.start_polling(self.bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(TelegramBot().main())

Modify your handlers to access the model and tokenizer from the injected data.
main_handler.py
async def main_handler(message: Message, model, tokenizer):
    result = run_model(model, tokenizer, message.text)
    await message.answer(result)

